# Exclude specific results exported in CSV via Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell and I am trying to exclude specific "GivenName" and "SN" when exporting results to a CSV.

This is my current script-

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Us00,OU=NA,Dd=corp,Dd=ads" -Filter {Enabled -eq $True} -Properties * | Select-Object GivenName, SN, DisplayName, Company, LastLogonDate |Where {($_.LastLogonDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)) -and ($_.LastLogonDate -ne $NULL)} | Export-Csv -Path G:\Conduct\InactiveUsers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

My goal is to Exclude any GivenName that may include the word "Agile" and OR exclude any SN that may include the word "External"

I have tried a where "is not" statement, but I am failing to reach my end goal. Any guidance or help would be appreciated

Comment: Add them to your filter like `Get-ADUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq $True -and (GivenName -notlike "*Agile*" -or SN -notlike "*External*")'`

Comment: the `-is` and `-isnot` operators are for comparing types like `"hello" -is [string]`. Powershell uses `-like` and `-notlike` for text comparison. Check out examples of all the operators here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.3

Answer (score 1):

Everything you're looking to do can be done leveraging the [Active Directory Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)):

```
$params = @{
    SearchBase = "OU=Us00,OU=NA,Dd=corp,Dd=ads"
    LDAPFilter =
        "(&" + # open the filter with AND
        "(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)" + # `Enabled`
        "(!givenName=*Agile*)" + # `GivenName` does not contain `Agile`
        "(!sn=*External*)" + # `sn` (Surname) does not contain `External`
        "(lastLogon<=$((Get-Date).AddDays(-30).ToFileTimeUtc()))" + # `lastLogon` is lower than or equal to 30 days ago
        "(lastLogon=*)" + # `lastLogon` attribute must be populated
        ")" # close the filter
    Properties = 'GivenName', 'SN', 'DisplayName', 'Company', 'LastLogonDate'
}
Get-ADUser @params | Select-Object $params['Properties'] |
    Export-Csv -Path G:\Conduct\InactiveUsers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**NOTE** - `lastLogon` attribute does not replicate across the Domain, because of this the query might not give you accurate results, you could however change the query to use `lastLogonTimeStamp` which indeed is replicated across Domain Controllers **but it's also not accurate**. See [**Understanding the AD Account attributes - LastLogon, LastLogonTimeStamp and LastLogonDate**](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22461.understanding-the-ad-account-attributes-lastlogon-lastlogontimestamp-and-lastlogondate.aspx).

If you need the most accurate results you would need to perform this query (targeting the `lastLogon` attribute) against all your Domain Controllers to find the latest authentication for all the users in the Domain. These answers might give you a hint on how you could approach querying all your DCs in case this was needed:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/68750430/15339544
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/72671034/15339544

Comment: You certainly guided me to the right direction, writing it in this format makes it run much more effeciently. 

I took your advice and wrote it as follows- 

        "(lastLogonTimeStamp<=$((Get-Date).AddDays(-30).ToFileTimeUtc()))" + # `lastLogon` is lower than or equal to 30 days ago
        "(lastLogonTimeStamp=*)" + # `lastLogon` attribute must be populated
        ")" # close the filter
    Properties = 'GivenName', 'SN', 'DisplayName', 'Company', 'LastLogonDate'

My results look more accurate, however my fear is that I may still have false positives.

Comment: @KeepVBSalive well yeah you should query all your DCs using `lastLogon` (what I would do) but that was not part of the question. The question was how to exclude `givenName` and `sn` :P