# Exporting last logon date for inactive users via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, automation, active-directory

I have a command that will export a list of users who have logged in for 12 months but I am struggling to export the last login date and time.

The command is as follows:

```
Search-ADAccount –AccountInActive -UsersOnly –TimeSpan 365:00:00:00 –ResultPageSize 2000 –ResultSetSize $null |?{$_.Enabled –eq $True} | Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, DistinguishedName, lastLogon| Export-CSV “C:\Users\Me\Desktop\InactiveUsers.CSV” –NoTypeInformation
```

But lastLogon is showing a blank in the CSV file.

I am new to PowerShell I understand the command can be made much smoother.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: You would need to pipe the result into `Get-ADUser -Properties` to get their last logon date

Comment: Something like: 

$date= (get-date).AddDays(-90)

Get-ADUser-Filter {LastLogonDate-lt $date} -Property Enabled|Where-Object {$_.Enabled -like “true”} |SelectName,SamAccountName,DistinguishedName,lastLogon|Export-CSV “C:\Users\Me\Desktop\InactiveUsers.CSV” -NoTypeInformation

Comment: The problem with lastlogontimestamp is that this attribute is not replicated in real time, there might be a delay of 14 days. If you want to get accurate results you should query all your domain controllers and use lastlogon instead, you can use this answer as an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/68750430/15339544

Comment: I will be honest with you its doe go over my head that code in the URL, I can understand what is is doing as you have explained it, but how would I tweak it for it script for users who haven't logged in for more than a year and display usernames, names, emails and last login date time stamp but to interrogate all DCs? (Sorry I am beginner in this field)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Search-ADAccount` doesn't have an option to pull other attributes from the AD Objects than the default ones, you can use `Get-ADUser` with an elaborate filter to query the users who haven't logged on for the past year. One option is to query the user's [`lastLogonTimeStamp` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-lastlogontimestamp) however by doing so you're risking not getting accurate results because this attribute is not replicated in real time. To get accurate results one must query the user's [`lastLogon` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-lastlogon) but, since this attribute is not replicated across the Domain, one must query all Domain Controllers to get the latest logon from the user.

For more information on this topic, please check this excellent TechNet Article: [**Understanding the AD Account attributes - LastLogon, LastLogonTimeStamp and LastLogonDate**](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22461.understanding-the-ad-account-attributes-lastlogon-lastlogontimestamp-and-lastlogondate.aspx).

```bash
$dateLimit = [datetime]::UtcNow.AddYears(-1).ToFileTimeUtc()

$AllDCs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter *
$logons = @{}

# NOTE:
#    - Use `!` for Enabled objects only: "(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)"
#      or remove the clause to find both, Enabled and Disabled users.
#    - The "(lastLogon<=$dateLimit)" clause can be removed to find all users latest login.
$params = @{
    LDAPFilter = -join @(
        '(&'                                                    # AND, all conditions must be met
            '(!samAccountName=krbtgt)'                          # exclude krbtgt from this query
            '(!samAccountName=Guest)'                           # exclude Guest from this query
            '(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)'    # Disabled objects only
            "(lastLogon<=$dateLimit)"                           # lastLogon is below the limit
        ')'                                                     # close AND clause
    )
    Properties = 'lastLogon'
    # Add `SearchBase = "OUPath"` here if targeting a specific OU
}

foreach ($DC in $AllDCs) {
    $params['Server'] = $DC

    foreach ($user in Get-ADUser @params) {
        # this condition is always met on first loop iteration due to ldap filtering condition
        if ($logons[$user.samAccountName].LastLogon -lt $user.LastLogon) {
            $logons[$user.samAccountName] = $user
        }
    }
}

$logons.Values | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name              = $_.Name
        SamAccountName    = $_.SamAccountName
        DistinguishedName = $_.DistinguishedName
        lastLogon         = [datetime]::FromFileTimeUtc($_.lastLogon).ToString('u')
    }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\InactiveUsers.CSV' -NoTypeInformation
```