# Export all AD account which has not authenticating in All AD domain controllers

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I wanted to list the user accounts which has not been authenticated at all in all domain controllers. Never login in all domain controllers mean no date set in the LastLogon attribute.

Example:

```
I have 36 DCs in total
User1 has LastLogonDate in DC1 and 2 --> do not show this user.
User2 has LastLogonDate in DC2 only --> do not show this user.
User3 has LastLogonDate in DC32 only --> do not show this user.

User4 has no LastLogonDate value in all 36 dcs --> this is the user to be added into the .CSV file.
User5 has no LastLogonDate value in all 36 dcs --> this is the user to be added into the .CSV file.
```

How can the function be modified, so it will only show or export the AD user account, where the last logon return  or  '1/01/1601 11:00:00 AM' in all $allDCs | ForEach-Object loop ?

Somehow the script below still returns or shows the account that has logged in just one AD Domain controller.

The total number of AD Domain Controllers I have is 36, so when the AD account does not have last logon date populated in all 36 DCs then it is what I want.

```
Function Get-ADLastLogonNever {
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]$SAMAccountName
)
    Begin {
        $allDCs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter *
    }
    Process {
        $neverLoggedOn = $true
        ForEach ($dc in $allDCs) {
            $adUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $SAMAccountName -Properties LastLogon, DisplayName -Server $dc.Name
            If ($_.lastLogon -gt 0) {
                $neverLoggedOn = $false
                Break
            }
        }
        If ($neverLoggedOn) {
            $adUser | Select-Object -Property `
                SamAccountName,
                DisplayName,
                @{n = 'DC'; e = {'<All>'}},
                @{n = 'LastLogon'; e = {'<Never>'}}
        }
    }
}

'IT Team', 'Finance Team', 'HR Team' |
    Get-ADGroupMember |
    Get-ADLastLogonNever |
    Export-Csv -Path C:\result.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You should really really use the AD Filter here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a slight variation from the code used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75337565/exporting-last-logon-date-for-inactive-users-via-powershell/75339028#75339028), it should help you find **all users who have never logged on** that are a `memberOf` any of the target groups.

Using the [AD Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)) is the way to go about this, the filtering should not be done with [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) when possible.

```bash
$AllDCs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter *
$logons = @{}

# construct a filter string to search those objects being a `memberof` these groups
$groupFilter = '(|'
'IT Team', 'Finance Team', 'HR Team' | Get-ADGroup | ForEach-Object {
    $groupFilter += '(memberOf={0})' -f $_.DistinguishedName
}
$groupFilter += ')'

$params = @{
    LDAPFilter = -join @(
        "(&"                            # AND, all conditions must be met
            "(!samAccountName=krbtgt)"  # exclude krbtgt from this query
            "(!samAccountName=Guest)"   # exclude Guest from this query
            "(|"                        # OR, any of the conditions must be met
                "(!lastLogon=*)"        # lastLogon is not set
                "(lastLogon=0)"         # never logged on
            ")"                         # close OR clause
            $groupFilter                # object is a member of any of the target Groups
        ")"                             # close AND clause
    )
    Properties = 'lastLogon', 'DisplayName'
}

foreach($DC in $AllDCs) {
    $params['Server'] = $DC

    foreach($user in Get-ADUser @params) {
        # if this user has not yet been hashed
        if(-not $logons.ContainsKey($user.DistinguishedName)) {
            # use its DN as Key and the value holds the instance and the counter
            $logons[$user.DistinguishedName] = @{
                Counter  = 1
                Instance = $user
            }
            continue
        }
        # if this user has been hashed before we only need to increase the counter
        $logons[$user.DistinguishedName]['Counter']++
    }
}

# for all collected users, filter them where the Counter equals to the amount of DCs
# meaning, they were found having the same LastLogon condition in all
$logons.Values | Where-Object { $_['Counter'] -eq $AllDCs.Count } | ForEach-Object {
    # here you can construct your desired output
    $instance = $_.Instance

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name              = $instance.Name
        SamAccountName    = $instance.SamAccountName
        DistinguishedName = $instance.DistinguishedName
        DisplayName       = $instance.DisplayName
        lastLogon         = [datetime]::FromFileTimeUtc($instance.lastLogon).ToString('u')
    }
} | Export-CSV C:\result.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hi @Santiago, thank you for the reply, however, there is no result when I executed the script as above, even with the updated Line #5 to supply the AD group sAMAccountName ? There is no error shown as well.

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer I think this was my bad, I forgot to remove `"(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)"` to search Disabled objects only. Give it a try again with the new update

Comment: Thanks @santiago, yes it works very fast.
I assume, I can add some more properties under [PSCustomObject] to show additional information?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer of course but if they're not default attributes displayed by `Get-ADUser` then you need to remember to add them to `Properties = 'lastLogon', 'DisplayName'` too

Answer (score 1):

I'd replace the `adUser` variable with:

```
$adUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $SAMAccountName -Properties LastLogonDate, DisplayName -Server $dc.Name | ? {$_.LastLogonDate -eq $null}
```

Then for the check below just change it to:

```
if ($adUser -ne $null){
    $neverLoggedOn = $false
    break
}
```

Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but, I'm pretty sure you don't even need the loop to check each DC as the `lastlogondate` property should be replicated throughout the domain. However, if you insist on doing it that way, and are using PowerShell Core, I'd suggest running your `ForEach` with the `-Parallel` parameter.

EDIT: So I reread your original post and realized I didn't contribute much to your original question. But I think I found why your code was breaking. Your if statement inside of the for loop is referencing the current `$PSItem` which would be the name of the DC, not your variable `$adUser`. So basically your variable is contributing nothing except for the property values in the if statement outside of your for loop. This is the code I came up with, basically the same except for that small change.

```
$neverLoggedOn = $true

foreach ($dc in $allDCs){
    $adUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $SAMAccountName -Properties LastLogon, DisplayName -Server $dc.Name

    if ($adUser.LastLogon -gt 0){
        $neverLoggedOn = $false
        break
    }
}

if ($neverLoggedOn){
    $adUser | Select-Object -Property `
        SamAccountName,
        DisplayName,
        @{n = 'DC'; e = {'<All>'}},
        @{n = 'LastLogon'; e = {'<Never>'}}
}
```

Comment: `lastlogondate` is not an AD Attribute, `lastlogontimestamp` is and yes, its replicated but not accurate. "The initial update after the raise of the domain functional level is calculated as 14 days minus random percentage of 5 days."

Comment: I ran the command at work and did indeed get something back for `lastlogondate`. I also ran it with the `lastlogontimestamp` property and my command would still work. However, I noticed that when using all three properties, `lastlogondate`, `lastlogontimestamp`, and `lastlogon`, some users had entries for `lastlogondate` and `lastlogontimestamp` but not `lastlogon`. It however was not the same when reversed. There were no users with `lastlogon` and NOT the other two.

Comment: That's because `lastLogon` is only set on the Domain Controller the user has authenticated with, hence the need to query all DCs to get accurate results

Comment: Ahh I learned something today, cool. Yeah, I just ran it with my own user account and sure enough, nothing popped up for those DCs in other cities.