# Function to find old AD machine logins

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to create a powershell function that will build a list of inactive computers on the network. I don't understand what i'm doing wrong and I hope someone can see my error,

```
Function Get-OldNames {
# to get an accurate list of machines that haven't logged in within a certain amount of time, we need to 
# query all the DCs in the domain then aggregate all the logins together to find the most recent to compare
# against. This function performs that search against the specified OU then returns a list of computer names
# as an array of strings 

    # Set the target OU
    $targetOU = "OU=Computers,OU=NewYork,OU=US,DC=contoso,DC=com"

    # Set the number of days to check for inactive computers
    $inactiveDays = -90
    [System.DateTime]$todaysDate = (Get-Date -Format d)
    $inactiveDate = $todaysDate.AddDays($inactiveDays)
    $inactiveDateValue = (Get-Date $inactiveDate).ToFileTime()

    # Get all domain controllers in the current domain
    $domainControllers = Get-ADDomainController -Filter *

    # Initialize an empty array to hold the results
    $inactiveComputers = @()

    # Loop through each domain controller and query for logons of computers in the target OU
    foreach ($dc in $domainControllers) {
            $dcName = $dc.Name
            Write-Host "Querying $dcName..."
            $inactiveComputers += Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Enabled -eq $true' -SearchBase $targetOU -Server $dcName -Properties LastLogon | Select-Object Name, LastLogon, @{Name='LastLogonAsDate';Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}}
    }

    # Sort the results by last logon time and filter the output
    return $inactiveComputers | Sort-Object LastLogon | Group-Object Name | Where-Object LastLogon -ge $inactiveDateValue | ForEach-Object Name
}
```

My error is that my list is empty no matter what I set the $inactivedays to, -90, -30, or whatever, makes no difference. If I change my filter in the return statement to be -le instead of -ge, I get the fill list of aggregated machine names. I can't see what I'm missing.

Comment: your filter `'Enabled -eq $true'` is finding active computers?

Comment: the code from this answer is what you want to do, just change `Get-ADUser` for `Get-ADComputer` and `.AddYears(-1)` for `.AddMonths(-3)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75337565/exporting-last-logon-date-for-inactive-users-via-powershell/75339028#75339028

Comment: I tried to implement this approached but it fails similarly to my own. The filter of Enabled is necessary since I'm only wanting to find machines objects that are enabled but have not logged in recently.

Comment: Then you would need to negate the filter `userAccountControl` filter so it only finds enabled objects: `"(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)"` (note the `!`)

Comment: Why ceate an array of objects with custom property `LastLogonAsDate` and then use property `LastLogon` in the return statement??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You grouped the results by Name before filtering by your `$inactiveDateValue`. The grouped results don't have a `LastLogon` property, and so `Where-Object` will say that `$null` is never greater than an `$inactiveDateValue`.

Here is how to check each group's last logon between each DC:

```bash
$inactiveDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$inactiveDays)
$inactiveComputers = foreach ($dc in $domainControllers) {
  $dcName = $dc.Name
  Write-Host "Querying $dcName..."
  
  Get-ADComputer -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True'" -Server $dcName -SearchBase $targetOU -Property LastLogonDate,LastLogon | 
    Select-Object Name, @{l='LastLogonDate';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}}
}

return $inactiveComputers | sort Name | Group Name | 
  # Check all last logons after grouping
  Where {-not ($_.Group.LastLogonDate -gt $inactiveDate)} |
  Select Name,
    # Optionally include all the returned dates to see
    @{l='MostRecentLogon';e={($_.Group.LastLogonDate | sort -desc) -join ', '}}
```

---

I prefer `LastLogonDate` for ease of reading and it's replicated between DCs. It's usually accurate enough (within 14 days) on any DC. Here are some other improvements

```
Function Get-OldNames {
  $inactiveDays = 90
  $targetOU = "OU=Computers,OU=NewYork,OU=US,DC=contoso,DC=com"

  # much faster to filter the ldap request 
  Get-ADComputer -Filter "LastLogonDate -lt '$((Get-Date).AddDays(-$inactiveDays))'" -SearchBase $targetOU -Property LastLogonDate,LastLogon | 
    Sort Name | 
    Select -ExpandProperty Name -Unique
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but i get results that don't include some machines that have the same dates as ones listed. My reason for Grouping by Name alone was to have only the most recent result returned for each computer name. If I included the LastLogon in the Group clause then I no longer have a single result for each machine name, i now get multiple entries for each machine, which defeats what i'm trying to accomplish.  I have to use the LastLogon since it's the only value that get's consistently updated. The 14 days out of sync isn't good enough. I can be a few hours off but I'd prefer not to be.

Comment: @EdR. I've added how to use the groups and `LastLogon` together. If any of the dates are newer than your inactive date, then it won't be in the list