# Powershell Login gives the same date for every user

Tags: powershell, active-directory

[image]When I run this command:

```
Get-AdUser -filter *  -Properties * | Select DisplayName,@{Name='LastLogon';Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}},LastLogonDate,@{Name='LastLogonTimestamp';Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimestamp).ToString('d MMMM')}}
```

I get the same date for the LastLogon attribute and now result for the LastLogonTimestamp attribute.

[image]

Comment: Those users never logged on. See the attribute details: "This value is stored as a large integer that represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC). A value of zero means that the last logon time is unknown." You should be using `FromFileTimeUtc` also.

Comment: mklement0, ofcourse those properties exist, I double checked in ADSI EDIT. Do you really think that I have 500 users in my AD that haven't logged in yet??

Comment: Santiago. Using FromFileTimeUtc doesn't make any difference. I get the same result.

Comment: you need to query all DCs to get an accurate LastLogon for all users. there are several examples in this site on how to do that, ie: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75339028/15339544

Comment: @Bob, I was speaking hypothetically, and my inference about the values being `$null` as the _only_ cause if the properties exist was incorrect: `0` produces the same symptom, and it sounds like that's the actual problem. Anyway, it looks like  Santiago's comment points to the right solution. His comment about using `::FromFileTimeUtc` instead of `::FromFileTime` was just _an aside_ that wasn't meant to solve the primary problem - AD timestamps are _UTC_ file times.