# Is there a way to pull a list of user attributes in Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to monitor the last logons of my users in Active Directory. I'm using the following script to set a user's lastlogon attribute as a variable.

$user1logon = (Get-ADUser - Identity $Username -Properties lastlogonTimestamp).lastlogonTimestamp

When I echo this variable it returns a value of 133340258148779315 for my test user. I assume this is Unix time?

To make this readable I'm trying to convert it with the following.

$reallogon = (Get-Date 01.01.1970).AddSeconds($user1logon)
($reallogon).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff")

Which returns this error message when run

Exception calling "AddSeconds" with "1" argument(s): "Value to add was out of range.
Parameter name: value"
At line:1 char:1

- $reallogon = (Get-Date 01.01.1970).AddSeconds($user1logon)
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException
  ```

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:2 char:1

- ($reallogon).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff")
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
  ```

I'm not super sure how to fix it as I'm new to scripting and Powershell, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Trying to pull a list of last logon dates from Active Directory

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

[`LastLogonTimeStamp` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-lastlogontimestamp) is represented in [FileTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime), to convert it into a `datetime` instance you can use the [`FromFileTimeUtc` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.fromfiletimeutc?view=net-7.0#system-datetime-fromfiletimeutc(system-int64)):

```bash
[datetime]::FromFileTimeUtc(133340258148779315)

# or to get a string in the desired format:
[datetime]::FromFileTimeUtc(133340258148779315).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff')
```

As aside, relying on `LastLogonTimeStamp` is not recommended to find a user's last logon, you should query all your Domain Controllers using the [`lastLogon` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-lastlogon) to get accurate results. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75339028/15339544) for details.