# Get random AD user from certain group where user needs to be active and lastlogintimestamp greater than 14 days

Tags: powershell, random, filter, active-directory

I need to get the name and SamAccountname of one random user that is in a specific group.

So far ive got the randomizer working as intented, but ass soon as i try to filter get-AdUser im sol.

this is what i have as of now:

```
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)

$randomUser = (Get-ADGroupMember GROUP) |Sort-Object{Get-random} | select -first 1 | Get-Aduser  -Properties name,SamAccountName  **#-filter {name -and SamaccountName -and LastLogonTimestamp -gt $date -and enabled -eq $true}**
```

As soon as i uncomment the bold part it stops working.

Any ideas and help would be apriciated.

I think its because i cannot filter on that output, but i dont know how to otherwise do it.
The reason im using lastlogontimestamp is because lastLogon is not replicated.

Comment: 1) `-Filter` should be a string, not a scriptblock. 2) what do you think you are filtering with `name -and SamaccountName`. 3) since you are piping the single random outcome of `Get-ADGroupMember`, use a Where-Object clause rather than `Filter` 4) `Get-ADGroupMember` also returns computer and group objects, not just users so Get-ADUser should only be used if you are certain you have a **user** object

Answer (score 0):

To complete [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo)'s comment, you cannot use the `-Filter` parameter here because data are pipelined (the objects you get with `Get-ADGroupMember`)

While this will be a very bad idea to have a group with users and computers into the same group, it is possible (even other groups or MSA/GMSA, etc...). So you need two filters, first one to get only users to send them to `Get-ADUser` and another one to to filter with LastlogonDate and Enabled :

The `lastLogonTimeStamp` is not a DateTime type but a long, so you need to convert your date `ToFileTimeUtc()` or `ToFileTime()` depending you want UTC or local time :

```
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14).ToFileTimeUtc()

Get-ADGroupMember "My Group" | Where-Object ObjectClass -eq "user" | 
   Get-ADUser -Properties lastLogonTimeStamp | 
   Where-Object { $_.lastLogonTimestamp -gt $date -and $_.Enabled } | Get-Random
```

`Get-Random` will return only one object (as you want), if you want more add `-Count <Number>`

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to filter for any **enabled** user being a `memberOf` the target group and having a `lastLogonTimeStamp` greater than 14 days ago instead of the other way around. Personally find it much easier and straight forward.

```
$groupDn = (Get-ADGroup theTargetGroup).DistinguishedName
$targetDate = [datetime]::UtcNow.AddDays(-14).ToFileTime()
$filter = -join @(
    "(&"                                                  # AND, all clauses must be met
        "(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)" # Enabled only
        "(!lastLogonTimeStamp<=$targetDate)"              # `lastLogonTimeStamp` "lower than or equal to" when negated means "greater than"
        "(memberOf=$groupDn)"                             # Object must be a `memberOf` the specified `distinguishedName`
    ")"                                                   # Closes AND
)

Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $filter | Get-Random
```

A notable mention, `lastLogonTimeStamp` is not a precise value, there is a 14 days margin, see [Understanding the AD Account attributes - LastLogon, LastLogonTimeStamp and LastLogonDate](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22461.understanding-the-ad-account-attributes-lastlogon-lastlogontimestamp-and-lastlogondate.aspx). For precision you must query all Domain Controllers and filter by `lastLogon` instead, in example: [Exporting last logon date for inactive users via PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75337565/exporting-last-logon-date-for-inactive-users-via-powershell/75339028#75339028)

Comment: @CFou not sure where you're taking that information from but I believe this comment to be inaccurate. My experience working on a huge Domain proves otherwise.

Comment: Well, I have mixed results, LDAP filters are better, but not 100%, so give a try, this one is better ;) (lastLogon and lastLogonTimeStamp are long, add `.ToFileTime()` to `$targetDate` one line 2)

Comment: @CFou good catch. thanks